# how to display html table in android(not vebview)?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application I do parsing xml and output the data in the required components on the phone screen, but there is a problem in that some of the data in the database stored in the form of html
is as headers and tables. In PHP when the browser opens, they are displayed correctly, but I also wanted to display in my android application.

This is something similar to the forum. A list of messages which can be a table or a text. I think the use `WebView` not rational. Maybe there is some sort of Components to display html in android except `WebView`?

Answer (score 0):

In Your Xml parser class create method.

```
public String stripHtml(String html) {
    html = html.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\>", " ");// Removes all items in
                                                // brackets
    html = html.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\\n", " ");// Must be undeneath
    html = html.replaceFirst("(.*?)\\>", " ");// Removes any connected item
                                                // to the last bracket
    html = html.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
    html = html.replaceAll("&amp;", " ");
    html = html.replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>", "");
    return html;
```

}

And call that method in.

```
public final String getElementValue(Node elem) {
    Node child;
    if (elem != null) {
        if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
                 return stripHtml(child.getNodeValue());
         }
    }
```

}
It's working for me to show some html data from xml.

Comment: Thank you, very valuable code. but another question. how to get html table in android without using webview?

Comment: you mean html table in your xml data??

Comment: in my android component. But what I do not know of Components

Comment: Well, I had already decided that most likely will have to use webView